# Extracting font from a handwritten pdf file

Tags: text-processing, font, font-utility, text

I'm wondering if it's possible to extract (create actually) the font from a handwritten pdf file. Online I found only methods to create a font starting from my own handwriting.

There are projects like [TextStyleBrush](https://about.fb.com/news/2021/06/ai-can-now-emulate-text-style-in-images-in-one-shot-using-just-a-single-word/#:%7E:text=We%E2%80%99re%20introducing-,TextStyleBrush,-%2C%20an%20AI%20research) by Meta, but it is not complete today.

Comment: Did you try [FineReader](https://support.abbyy.com/hc/en-us/articles/360004000080-Recognition-of-handwritten-text-in-FineReader-PDF)?